# Stone falling from the edge of a cliff

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, displacement

A rock is thrown straight upward from the edge of a 30m cliff, rising 10m, then falling all the way down the base of the cliff. Find the displacement.

Well, because the rock was thrown 10m up, and then it came all the way down, I added those quantities (10m+30m) so I got 40m. But since the displacement is the object's initial position to its final position, regardless of the path actually taken, would I have to count the rock before it was thrown? Then the answer would be 30m

Comment: I agree with your definision of displacement, and [so does Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_(vector)).

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

The displacement would be the distance between the edge of the cliff and the ground. So, the answer is 30m (taking into account vectors, -30m since it's in the negative X-direction). This is because, displacement is simply the change in position of an object. Since, the object only really changes it's position by 30m,  that's the displacement.

However, you would be correct in saying the  **distance**  travelled by the object is  **50m**  not  **40m**  considering it only moves  **vertically** . This is because it moves 10m up, comes down 10m and then descends another 30m to the ground. So  **10m + 10m + 30m = 50m** .

If the object however, has some horizontal velocity component, it would be parabolic distance but I don't think that's the case here.